# Массив битов

Tags: множества, массивы, c++

Задача следующая: Реализовать представление множеств в памяти ЭВМ в программе, которая по заданным множествам A, B, C, D строчных русских букв вычисляет множество, содержащее все буквы из A и все буквы из B, но не содержащего букв, являющихся общими для C и D.

Нужно это все дело сделать через массив битов. Помогите пожалуйста с чего начать, да и что вообще из себя представляет этот массив битов, и как задать множества?

Comment: Вот тут-то и вылезает во всей красе буква **ё**. Без нее, достаточно 32-бит, т.е. *int*. 

А с ней придется взять **long long** (64 бита). Конечно, если Вы хотите экономить память (в ущерб скорости), то можно использовать массив из 5 байт.

Для операций с такими множествами (умещающимися в машинное слово (двойное слово) (только не в терминологии M$)) достаточно операций & | ~ и << из языка С++/C.

Т.е. (без ё) 

    int x1 = A & B; //  множество, содержащее все буквы из A и все буквы из B
    int x2 = C & D; // общие для С и D

и если не ошибаюсь

    int your_result = x1 & ~x2

(места мало)

Comment: @avp: ладно вам на букву Ё жаловаться :) вон в венгерском алфавите 40 букв, что ж им, ради эффективности от 8 букв отказываться?

Comment: @avp: `int x1 = A | B;`?

Comment: @VladD, конечно, **|**. Просто ошибся (с точностью до наоборот).

Comment: @VladD, 
> вон в венгерском алфавите 40 букв, что ж им, ради эффективности от 8 букв отказываться?

Нет там 40 букв. Там стандартная латиница + варианты с акьютом и умляутом (öüőűóéáí). Cs, Dz, Gy и пр. скорее не являются самостоятельным буквами, а диграфами.

Comment: @gecube: хм, а с точки зрения кодовых страниц это всё одна буква или по нескольку? Потому что у нас речь шла именно об этом. Вот тут ещё [несколько языков](http://www.drozdovland.ru/index.php?id=1419), включая армянский и грузинский, там тоже под сорок, и вроде бы без акцентов и лигатур.

Comment: @VladD, Cs, Sz, Gy, Ly и пр. - с т.з. набора текста ДВЕ БУКВЫ.

Comment: Понятно, есть языки, которым в плане эффективности обработки текстов совсем не повезло (китайский, например), а есть английский, который в 32 бит укладывается. 

Нам же чуть-чуть не повезло с количеством букв и **сильно** не повезло, что кириллица, а не Latin1 (тем более не ascii).

Ну, с кириллицей бороться бессмысленно, а вот с ё...

Comment: @avp: если к 26 буквам латинского алфавита ещё добавить пробел, знаки препинания (точка, запятая, тире, двоеточие, точка с запятой, кавычки), которые нужны в текстах, уже получается 33. Плюс ещё заглавные буквы. А ещё в английском используются акценты для заимствованных слов. Так что экономии в реальности наверняка не получится и в английском.

Comment: @VladD, напомню, речь шла о *множестве* ***строчных букв***. Их в английском (ASCII, а не LATIN-1) ровно 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте по пунктам.

Массив битов в C++ есть, даже целых два: [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) и [`std::bit_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Вы, понятно, на их основе должны построить понятие множества: элемент номер `n` входит в множество тогда и только тогда, когда `n`-ый бит в массиве установлен в 1. (Замечу, что в реальной жизни лучше просто использовать готовый [`std::set<wchar_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)).

Как представить себе буквы при помощи битового массива. В принципе, как угодно: например, каждой букве сопоставить индекс, равный её номеру в алфавите. Или коду символа, что наверное проще.

Далее, подумайте, какие операции над множествами вам надо реализовать? Очевидно, объединение, пересечение и разность. Как их реализовать? Проще всего "побитно": например, для разности проверяете `i`-ый бит уменьшаемого и вычитаемого, и в разности устанавливаете этот бит тогда и только тогда, когда в уменьшаемом он 1, а в вычитаемом 0. То же для остальных операций.

Вот вроде бы и всё для начала. Дерзайте!

---

Пример кода:

```
vector<bool> subtract_sets(
    const vector<bool>& minuend, const vector<bool> subtrahend)
{
    unsigned int size = minuend.size();
    if (size != subtrahend.size())
        throw invalid_argument("sizes must be the same");
    vector<bool> difference(size);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        bool minuend_has_i = minuend[i];
        bool subtrahend_has_i = subtrahend[i];
        bool difference_has_i = minuend_has_i && !subtrahend_has_i;
        difference[i] = difference_has_i;
    }
    return difference;
}
```

(Для пуристов: да, я знаю про `decltype`, итераторы и `<algorithm>`, но этот пример специально такой, чтобы быть понятным новичку. А [это](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) насчёт возврата по значению.)

Comment: а можно небольшой пример кода?

Comment: Примеры есть по указанным ссылкам. А выбрать, наверное, лучше bitset, поскольку там есть битовые операции над множетсвами.

Comment: @skies: добавил пример операции

Comment: @alexlz: в bitset template, может быть новичку рано? на всякий случал дал пример с vector.

Comment: Вот только непонятно, зачем исключение выбрасывать через new. Тогда ведь будет передаваться потенциальной ловушке не сам объект исключения, а указатель на него. Да и удалять его потом отдельно придется... Пользователь функции может попасть в неприятную ситуацию.

Comment: @mikillskegg: хм, привычка из C#. А правда, как лучше? Если делать не по указателю, не будет ли вызываться лишний конструктор копирования? (Хотя, преждевременная оптимизация и всё такое.) Как принято среди взрослых программистов?

Comment: >Как принято среди взрослых программистов?

))))

Обычно так

    throw invalid_argument("sizes must be the same");

А чтобы не вызывался лишний конструктор, ловушка должна принимать *ссылку* на объект

    try{
       ...
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
       .....
    }

Comment: @mikillskegg: о, const&, классно! Спасибо, запомню на будущее. Вот как раз обсуждение по теме: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference

Answer (score 1):

[Набросал тут](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/vcfEV/)... Реализация на javascript'е. int32 и битовые операции, для любой длины алфавита. Проходов конечно много, массив лениво заводить было )